# Strange right-click options

Tags: windows-8

UPDATE:

Following is the image to show the button on my laptop (Dell N5110). It automatically turns on and the moment it turns on, mouse loses its control and starts showing this "strange" right-click options, etc. As mentioned earlier, I have shown it to a hardware engineer as well but of no use. I hope someone would be experienced enough on the community to help me out there. Thanks

[image]I had been experiencing this on my laptop (Win 8.1). Basically what happens is that I am using a laptop and all the sudden out of nowhere this right-click menu opens and after it systems gets sort of stuck as it doesn't let me do my work and this menu keeps opening.

Someone said it can be due to some virus. I have reinstalled the Windows but no, its still showing same. Please have a look on the screenshot:

Plus as many people have pointed it out, my Windows is 8.1 and even if it had been Windows 10, this unexpected menu opening without any reason is quite annoying as it leaves me stranded. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Any help will be valuable

***UPDATE***

I have changed Keyboard and problem is still there :/

Comment: If you installed Windows again, and you are getting the same right click options, then it isn't a virus.  The context menu in the screenshot is default behavior.

Comment: ...it's the infamous virus called Windows? ;)

Comment: I'm curious as to which options on that context menu you consider "strange" ??  they all look pretty basic options for Windows to me ??

Comment: lol class stacker. Obviously its not a virus. Do you all get these options when you right click on a screen?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - Yes

Comment: That's the WinX menu. It comes up when you right-click the Start button, or press Windows-X on the keyboard. If it's coming up by itself, there may be a problem with your keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is a different right click menu than you are probably use to seeing in say Windows 7 but this is the default right click menu in Windows 10. Nothing is wrong with the menu.

[image: I don't have my laptop with Windows 10 on it with me but here is an image I found on Google images]

Comment: This is the correct answer but can you add a screenshot as additional proof?

Comment: I have been using Win 10 on other laptop since August. Never experienced it I am afraid